# set active class with php

Tags: php, mysql

I need to get class active on menu based on pages. for example, when in homepage, the home menu will have class "active" and same with another pages.
here my code

```
<?php
    $basename = substr(strtolower(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])),0,strlen(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']))-4);
    $menu = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM menu order by id_menu asc");
    while($m=mysql_fetch_array($menu)){   
        echo "<a href='$m[name].htm' class='";
        if ($basename=='$m[name]'){
            echo "active";
        }else{
            echo "none";
        }
        echo "'>$m[text]</a>";
    }
?>
```

and this is menu table in mysql

```
id_menu    name     text
1          index    Home
2          concept  Concept
3          gallery  Gallery
```

and etc..

and the files name same value in name field

But when I refresh in browser, it doesn't work at all. Please help me

Comment: For simplification declare page variable on each menu page and compare that variable with menu item coming from database is both match apply active class .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'$m[name]'` is a string, remove the single quotes to get the value of `$m[name]` in your `if` when comparing

Comment: Glad I could help ;)
Don't forget, never trust user input !

Answer (score 1):

Next time, make your code a bit cleaner please :)

```
echo '<a href="'.$m[name].'" class="'.($basename=='$m[name]') ? "active" : "none".'">'.$m[text].'</a>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply replace instead of using substring.
Remove the quotes around the variable in your compare statement

```
<?php
$basename = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SERVER']); // Get the basename
$basename = strtolower($basename); // Convert to lowercase
$basename = str_replace('.php', '', $basename); // Replace ".php" with ""
//Your database as PHP array for demo purpose
$menu = array(
    array('id_menu' => 1, 'name' => 'index', 'text' => 'Home'),
    array('id_menu' => 2, 'name' => 'concept', 'text' => 'Concept'),
    array('id_menu' => 3, 'name' => 'gallery', 'text' => 'Gallery')
);

for($i = 0; $i < count($menu); $i++) {
    $m = $menu[$i];
    $class = $basename === $m['name'] ? 'active' : '';
    echo "<a href=\"$m[name].htm\" class=\"$class\">$m[text]</a>";
}
```